How to Efficiently Pause a Printer Job Before Printing in C#
I'm working on a C# application to monitor and manage printer jobs. My goal is to pause a print job as soon as it is added to the printer queue before it starts printing. However, I'm facing some issues with the timing and reliability of pausing the job, especially when dealing with different printer drivers and job sizes.
Here's what I have done so far:

Opened the printer and set up change notifications:

IntPtr hPrinter;
if (!OpenPrinter(printerName, out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Log($"Failed to open printer: {printerName}. Error code: {errorCode}");
    return;
}

IntPtr hChange = FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinter, PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB | PRINTER_CHANGE_WRITE_JOB | PRINTER_CHANGE_SET_JOB, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
if (hChange == IntPtr.Zero)
{
    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Log($"Failed to create change notification for printer: {printerName}. Error code: {errorCode}");
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    return;
}



Monitoring the printer for changes:

while (bKeepMonitoring && !cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    uint waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(hChange, 1000);
    if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
    {
        int pdwChange;
        IntPtr lppPrinterNotifyInfo;
        bool fcnreturn = FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hChange, out pdwChange, IntPtr.Zero, out lppPrinterNotifyInfo);

        if (fcnreturn)
        {
            if ((pdwChange & PRINTER_CHANGE_ADD_JOB) != 0)
            {
                Log($"A new print job was added to printer: {printerName}");
                JOB_INFO_1? jobInfo = PausePrintJob(hPrinter);
                if (jobInfo != null)
                {
                    Log($"Job paused: {jobInfo.Value.JobId}, Document: {jobInfo.Value.pDocument}");
                }
            }
            // Additional handling for other events
        }
        else
        {
            int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Log($"Failed to get next printer change notification for printer: {printerName}. Error code: {errorCode}");
            bKeepMonitoring = false;
        }
    }
    else if (waitResult == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    {
        Log("Timeout...");
    }
    else
    {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        Log($"WaitForSingleObject failed for printer: {printerName}. Error code: {errorCode}");
        bKeepMonitoring = false;
    }
}


Pausing the print job:

private static JOB_INFO_1? PausePrintJob(IntPtr hPrinter)
{
    uint needed = 0, returned = 0;
    IntPtr buffer = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 1, buffer, 0, out needed, out returned);
        if (needed == 0)
        {
            Log("No job to pause.");
            return null;
        }

        buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)needed);
        if (EnumJobs(hPrinter, 0, 1, 1, buffer, needed, out needed, out returned) && returned > 0)
        {
            JOB_INFO_1 jobInfo = (JOB_INFO_1)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(JOB_INFO_1));
            Log($"Pausing job: {jobInfo.JobId}, Document: {jobInfo.pDocument}");

            if (!SetJob(hPrinter, jobInfo.JobId, 0, IntPtr.Zero, JOB_CONTROL_PAUSE))
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                Log($"Failed to pause job: {jobInfo.JobId}. Error code: {errorCode}");
            }
            else
            {
                return jobInfo;
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

Problem:
Despite setting a low polling interval and handling different notification events, there are still cases where the print job starts printing before it gets paused, especially with certain printer drivers or large print jobs. I occasionally get a "paused - printing" status instead of a "paused" status.
Questions:
What can be done to ensure that the job is paused immediately upon being added to the queue?
Are there specific printer drivers or configurations that work better for this kind of job control?
How can I improve the timing and reliability of detecting and pausing the print job before it starts printing?
Additional Information:
I'm using the "Generic / Text Only" printer driver for testing.
I've tried different timeout values for WaitForSingleObject.
The application is running with administrative privileges.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Open the Print Management, right click the printer and select Pause Printing

In Powershell you can do Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Printer | where Name -eq "Your Printer" | Invoke-CimMethod -Method Pause

Now that it works in Powershell, you can use WMI to do the same thing.

@Charlieface thanks for help. I cannot pause the printer in c# so change the script to the Powershell version. When the app starts it paused initially.

You can use CimInstance directly from C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.management.infrastructure.ciminstance?view=powershellsdk-7.4.0
